# iOS: How to disable UISegmentControl without "dimm"- effect?

Tags: ios

I try to integrate a UISegmentControl to my app which should only display a current status. This means i do not want the SegmentControl to be touchable.

I tried:

```
passwdStrength = (UISegmentedControl *)[cell viewWithTag:99];
tintcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[passwdStrength setTintColor:tintcolor];
[passwdStrength setTitle:lang(@"PW_STRENGTH_WEAK") forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[passwdStrength setTitle:lang(@"PW_STRENGTH_MEDIUM") forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[passwdStrength setTitle:lang(@"PW_STRENGTH_STRONG") forSegmentAtIndex:2];
passwdStrength.enabled = NO;
passwdStrength.alpha = 1.0f;
```

The SegmentControl is not touchable anymore but the colors (i switch between red, yellow, green) are dimmed. I searched an answer and found the info that the alpha value of the segment is set to 0.5f when it is disabled. Because of that i tried to set the alpha value manually to 1 but it does not work.

Anybody an idea how to disable the touch on UISegmentControl without dimming the color of the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not to disable the `UISegmentedControl`, but to disable the *userInteraction* on it. That way, the "dimm" effect is not applied, and the user can't click on the control.

If you're using interface builder (xib / storyboard), select your `UISegmentedControl`, and here's what the config should look like:

[image: Interface Builder]

If you want to do it by code:

```
passwdStrength.enabled = YES;
passwdStrength.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

**UISegmentedControl** is a subclass of **UIControl** which in turn is a subclass of **UIView** so you could set the **userInteractionEnabled** property to equal **NO** for the control. This will prevent touches on the segmented control.